# .NET RestAPI Update Record Error

Tags: c#, sql, rest

I am updating a record via a RestAPI as follows:

```
if (contactstatus.Contact_Status_ID == 2)
{
  contactstatus.Contact_Status_ID = 1;                
  Dictionary<string, object> activestatus = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
 {"Contact_Status_ID", contactstatus.Contact_Status_ID}
};                    _formRest.UsingAuthenticationToken(token).UpdateRecord("Contacts", contactId, activestatus);
```

I get a `System.NullReferenceException` on the last line. The value of the column is an int. What could I be messing up here?

Comment: Try debugging and hovering with your mouse cursor over _formRest. If it's not null, probably UsingAuthenticationToken(token) returns null.

Comment: Second Dido's suggestion

Comment: According to the API documentation contactID is not used but cannot be null. I set it to -1 and it ran perfectly. Thanks!